# Prerequisite of Ubuntu Server 20.04.2

Tags: server

I want to install Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 in virtualbox on Windows 10.
Should I plug in ethernet or wired network to my notebook?
Or is it possible run the Ubuntu Server just using Wi-Fi?
Thank you.

Comment: It does not matter which you choose on the host. The Guest server will see only an "ethernet" connection provided by your VirtualBox Host. It's not a *real* ethernet connection -- it just seems like one to the Guest.

Comment: so, whether I use ethernet or wi-fi is okay to run it?